# Make new column by turning each row into a dict in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, class, oop

So I have have created a pandas dataframe from the following csv:

```
id  age00   education   marital gender  ethnic  industry    income00
0   51.965         17         0      1       0         5    76110
1   41.807         12         1      0       0         1    43216
2   36.331         12         1      0       1         3    52118
3   56.758          9         1      1       2         2    47770
```

My goal is to create a new column called **future_income** which takes each row and calculates future income using my model.

This is done by the **predictFinalIncome** variable in a class I created below:

```
class myModel:
  def __init__(self, bias) :
    self.bias = bias # bias is a dictionary with info to set bias on the gender function and the ethnic function


  def b_gender(self, gender):
    effect = 0
    if (self.bias["gender"]): # if there is gender bias in this model/world (from the constructor) 
      effect = -0.0005 if (gender<1) else 0.0005  # This amount to 1.2% difference annually
    return self.scale * effect

  def b_ethnic(self, ethnic):
    effect = 0
    if (self.bias["ethnic"]): # if there is ethnic bias in this model/world (from the constructor) 
      effect = -0.0007 if (ethnic < 1) else -0.0003 if (ethnic < 2) else 0.0005 
    return self.scale * effect


  # other methods/functions
  def predictGrowthFactor( self, person ): # edited
    factor = 1 + person['education'] + person['marital'] + person['income'] + person['industry']
    return factor

  def predictIncome( self, person ): # perdict the new income one MONTH later. (At least on average, each month the income grows.)
    return person['income']*self.predictGrowthFactor( person )

  def predictFinalIncome( self, n, person ): 
    n_income = self.predictIncome( person )
    for i in range(n):
       n_income = n_income * i
    return n_income
```

n in this case is 120.

So in short. I would like to take each row, throw it into the class function called **predictFinalIncome** and have a new variable on my df called future_income, which is their income in 120 months.

EDIT:

I actually don't need the person class. I accidentally removed my init__ in the class which determines the argument 'bias'. Instead, based off @Cavin Dsouza's code. But this doesnt work.

The code is then read in like:

```
utopModel = myModel( { "gender": False, "ethnic": False } ) # no bias


n =120
#Utopia
u = utopModel
world1['incomeFinal_utop'] = world1.apply(lambda row: u.predictFinalIncome(n, row), axis=1)
```

So the error is this when it goes to the predictFinalIncome:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError        

KeyError: 'income'
```

Comment: So say your dataframe is `df`, and you create an object of class `myModel` like `m = myModel()`, wouldn't you able to simply create a column `future_income` as - `df['future_income'] = df.apply(lambda row: m.predictFinalIncome(n, row), axis=1)` ? Here, `row` inside the `apply` function acts as a Person object, so maybe the Person class wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just making it very complicated, all the calculation you did can actually be done by just one function unless you need your intermediate results for other usages.

You can create a function that can be applied to each row of your dataframe:

```
def predictFinalIncome(row, n):
    factor = 1 + row['education'] + row['marital'] + row['income'] + row['industry']
    n_income = row['income'] * factor
    for i in range(n):
        n_income = n_income * i
    return n_income
```

Then, use `df.apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda r: predictFinalIncome(r, 120), axis=1)
```

It's returning 0 because when you do `for i in range(n)`, you actually start with 0, so the result will always be 0. That you need to fix it.

---

**Update: make the function live inside the `Model` class**

I don't see obvious reason for this function to live inside the Model from your posting especially this function doesn't use any of the other methods nor the bias attribute you created, but here it is.

```
class myModel:
    def __init__(self, bias) :
        self.bias = bias

    def predictFinalIncome(self, row, n):
        factor = 1 + row['education'] + row['marital'] + row['income'] + row['industry']
        n_income = row['income'] * factor
        for i in range(n):
            n_income = n_income * i
        return n_income

# to use:
model = myModel(bias)
df.apply(lambda r: model.predictFinalIncome(r, 120), axis=1)
```

Comment: Okay this is solid; except I need the function to exist in the class, for other usages. So is there a way I can reference the class function within the apply ?

Comment: Which class you still want to keep, Model or Person? I don't see a reason for having Person class, but your current Model class uses Person class, so I'm not sure how exactly you want this to work.

Comment: I see; okay I clarified the problem above; you are right, I do not need Person just myModel. That myModel has parameters, so I save that to an object and run however I get an error. This function does have to exist in the class myModel

Comment: @JohnnyThomas you had the wrong parameter order, `r` comes first, and then `n`.

Comment: My code is written the other way around so I have to put n first. We can keep it your way for the demonstration.
I think the dilemma is coming up when using specific values for bias. Your code produces the same error I am getting when I specify a value for bias.
```model = myModel( { "gender": False, "ethnic": False })```

If this weren't the case then I think we would be smooth sailing

Comment: @JohnnyThomas I don't get error from `model = myModel( { "gender": False, "ethnic": False })`, I'm not sure what you are doing that gave you the error. And I don't see you using bias anywhere in the code posted so I can't pin down the problem

Comment: added into example

Comment: I see your problem. In your dataset you posted, you had `income00` as column name, but when extracting, you are using `row["income"]`, which doesn't match. You need to be consistent with your naming

Comment: *Homer simpson backs into shrubs* Thank you TYZ!